# OpenNetCF.IOC event subscription not firing

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-ce, opennetcf, opennetcf.ioc

I am developing a Vb.net .Net 3.5 PDA application using the OpenNetCF IOC framework. I have set up and event to handle the navigation through the smart parts but when I raise the event the EventSubscription does not fire.

I am sure I have missed something simple but would appreciate so advice.

```
Imports OpenNETCF
Imports OpenNETCF.IoC
Imports OpenNETCF.IoC.UI

Public Class MainContainer

    <EventPublication(EventNames.Navigate)> _
    Public Event NavigateToSmartPart As EventHandler(Of GenericEventArgs(Of SmartPart))

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        RootWorkItem.Items.Add(workspace, WorkspaceNames.StackWorkspace)

        RootWorkItem.Services.AddOnDemand(Of XMLWrapper)()
        RootWorkItem.Services.AddOnDemand(Of DataInterface)()

        'RootWorkItem.SmartParts.AddNewDisposable(Of ViewCamera)()
        RootWorkItem.SmartParts.AddNew(Of ViewGoodInInspection)()
        RootWorkItem.SmartParts.AddNew(Of ViewLogon)()
        RootWorkItem.SmartParts.AddNew(Of ViewPartCentre)()
        RootWorkItem.SmartParts.AddNew(Of ViewSplash)()

    End Sub

    Private Sub MainContainer_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        RootWorkItem.Services.Get(Of DataInterface)().InitialseApplication()

        If RootWorkItem.Services.Get(Of XMLWrapper)().LoadPartCentreID.Equals(UInt16.MinValue) Then
            RaiseEvent NavigateToSmartPart(Me, New GenericEventArgs(Of SmartPart)(RootWorkItem.SmartParts.Get(Of ViewPartCentre).First))
        Else
            RaiseEvent NavigateToSmartPart(Me, New GenericEventArgs(Of SmartPart)(RootWorkItem.SmartParts.Get(Of ViewSplash).First))
        End If

    End Sub

    <EventSubscription(EventNames.Navigate, ThreadOption.Caller)> _
    Public Sub NavigateSmartPart(Of T As SmartPart)()
        'Public Sub NavigateSmartPart(Of T As SmartPart)()
        workspace.Show(RootWorkItem.SmartParts.Get(Of t).First)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

It was do to a requirement that the startup object is Sub Main and that class inherits from SmartClientApplication(Of Form).

```
Imports OpenNETCF.IoC.UI

Namespace OpenNetCF_Events_CSharp
    Public Class Startup
        Inherits SmartClientApplication(Of Form1)

        Public Shared Sub Main()
            Dim appStarter As New Startup
            appStarter.Start()
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

It requires this in order to allow the items, smart parts and services to wire up the event correctly.

Phil

Comment: Actually this isn't 100% true.  To be wired together they publisher and subscriber instances simply must be added to the same IoC container.  Not adding one (subscriber or publisher) is the most common reason for the event to not fire.  Sorry I didn't see this question earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Chris,

I am also getting an error message when creating new smart parts that have EventPublication setup.

MAIN FORM

```
RootWorkItem.SmartParts.AddNew(Of ViewLogon)()

<EventSubscription(EventNames.Navigate, ThreadOption.UserInterface)> _
Public Sub NavigateSmartPart(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GenericEventArgs(Of String))
    workspace.Show(RootWorkItem.SmartParts.Get(e.Value))
End Sub
```

NEW SMART PART

```
<EventPublication(EventNames.Navigate)> _
Public Event NavigateToSmartPart As EventHandler(Of GenericEventArgs(Of String))
```

Its throwing a Target Invokation error (Inner Exception NullReferenceException) in the below method on the else if (ctors.Count() == 1) line.

```
internal static object CreateObject(Type t, WorkItem root)
{
    object instance = null;

    // first check the cache
    if(m_constructorCache.ContainsKey(t))
    {
        return CreateObjectFromCache(t, root);
    }

    ConstructorInfo ci;

    if (t.IsInterface)
    {
        throw new IOCException(string.Format("Cannot create an instance of an interface class ({0}). Check your registration code.", t.Name));
    }


    // see if there is an injection ctor
    var ctors = (from c in t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                 where c.IsPublic == true
                 && c.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectionConstructorAttribute), true).Count() > 0
                 select c);

    if (ctors.Count() == 0)
    {
        // no injection ctor, get the default, parameterless ctor
        var parameterlessCtors = (from c in t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                  where c.GetParameters().Length == 0
                                  select c);
        if (parameterlessCtors.Count() == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type '{0}' has no public parameterless constructor or injection constructor.\r\nAre you missing the InjectionConstructor attribute?", t));
        }

        // create the object
        ci = parameterlessCtors.First();
        try
        {
            instance = ci.Invoke(null);
            m_constructorCache.Add(t, new InjectionConstructor { CI = ci });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
    else if (ctors.Count() == 1)
    {
        // call the injection ctor
        ci = ctors.First();
        ParameterInfo[] paramList = ci.GetParameters();
        object[] inputs = GetParameterObjectsForParameterList(paramList, root, t.Name);
        try
        {
            instance = ci.Invoke(inputs);
            m_constructorCache.Add(t, new InjectionConstructor { CI = ci, ParameterList = paramList });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type '{0}' has {1} defined injection constructors.  Only one is allowed", t.Name, ctors.Count()));
    }
    // NOTE: we don't do injections here, as if the created object has a dependency that requires this instance it would fail becasue this instance is not yet in the item list.

    return instance;
}
```

Call stack

```
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ObjectFactory.AddCollectionEventHandlers[TKey,TItem](Object instance, IEnumerable`1 collection, PublicationDescriptor[] sourceEvents, SubscriptionDescriptor[] eventSinks)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ObjectFactory.AddEventHandlers(Object instance, WorkItem root, Boolean walkUpToRoot)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ObjectFactory.AddEventHandlers(Object instance, WorkItem root)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ObjectFactory.DoInjections(Object instance, WorkItem root)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ManagedObjectCollection`1.Add(ISmartPart item, String id, Boolean expectNullId)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ManagedObjectCollection`1.AddNew(Type typeToBuild, String id, Boolean expectNullId, Boolean wrapDisposables)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ManagedObjectCollection`1.AddNew(Type typeToBuild)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ManagedObjectCollection`1.AddNew[TTypeToBuild]()
   at GoodsInInspection.MainContainer..ctor()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeConstructorInfo rtci, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ObjectFactory.CreateObject(Type t, WorkItem root)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ManagedObjectCollection`1.AddNew(Type typeToBuild, String id, Boolean expectNullId, Boolean wrapDisposables)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ManagedObjectCollection`1.AddNew(Type typeToBuild)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.ManagedObjectCollection`1.AddNew[TTypeToBuild]()
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.UI.SmartClientApplication`1.Start(IModuleInfoStore store)
   at OpenNETCF.IoC.UI.SmartClientApplication`1.Start()
   at GoodsInInspection.Startup.Main()
```

If I remove the EventPublication attribute from the event then the smart part is created successfully.

Comment: Nevermind. I have sorted it. Looks like an issue with using the Service.AddOnDemand over the Service.AddNew